# Java Regex Help on \p{Punct}

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regexes, one with `\p{Punct}` and the other one without

Snippet (1):

```
add(\s[\w\p{Punct}]+)+(\s#\w+)*
```

Snippet (2):

```
add(\s[\w]+)+(\s#\w+)*
```

If I input "add buy an egg #grocery testing", it will result matching in (1) but not matching in (2). Any idea what is happening?

Comment: weird, I am trying it here http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html that (1) matches while the other one does not match (lol, I just realised, you are using Javasript regex, not Java)

Comment: But `add(\s[\w]+)+(\s#\w+)*` does match "`add buy an egg #grocery` testing", is that not correct ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second regex allows `#` to be only at start of last matched word in string stating with "add" while in your sentence `#` exists in word which wasn't last.
`\p{Punct}` is character class which also includes `#` character so class like `[\w\p{Punct}]` lets you match

- `\w` alphabetic characters, digits and `_`
- and `\p{Punct}` punctuation: one of `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ ``

which lets `#grocery` be matched even if it is not the last word.